# All properties of child component reference created with React.createRef() is undefined in the componentDidMount method

Tags: reactjs, froala

I have a React component that renders another component from a third party library, Froala Editor. I store a reference to the child component using React.createRef().

In the componentDidMount method, I am trying to access methods in the child reference. However, those methods are returning undefined. Now, I tried doing console.log on the child reference itself and I see those methods are NOT undefined.

The child component also accepts callbacks and I have use cases where I am able to use the methods just fine. However, when I use the reference in componentDidMount the inner props are all undefined.

I'm a newbie with React so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FroalaEditor from "react-froala-wysiwyg";
import styled from "styled-components";

const CustomStyle = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => (props.isEditOn ? "white" : "unset")};
  padding: ${props => props.padding || "2px"};
  width: ${props =>
    props.width ||
    (props.isPlaceholderVisible ? props.placeholderTextWidth : "unset")};
  white-space: ${props => (props.multiLine ? "wrap" : "nowrap")};
`;

class CustomInlineFroalaEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isPlaceholderVisible: false,
      isEditOn: false
    };
    this.editorRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.text) {
      this.setState({ isPlaceholderVisible: true });
    }
    console.log(this.getEditorFromReactRef()); //logs the reference just fine. Looking at the log seems like .html in next line should not be undefined
    console.log(this.getEditorFromReactRef().html); //returns undefined..but why?
  }

  handleKeyUp = event => {
    const editor = this.getEditorFromReactRef();
    if (event.key === "Enter" && !this.props.multiLine) {
      this.handleEnter(editor);
    }
  };

  handleEnter = editor => {
    // these commands work just fine so I'm confused as to why the ref in componentDidMount is behaving oddly
    editor.edit.off();
    editor.edit.on();
    this.setState({ isEditOn: false });
    this.handlePlaceholderVisibleOnBlur(editor);
    if (typeof this.props.onEnter === "function") {
      this.props.onEnter();
    }
  };

  handleBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ isEditOn: false });
    this.handlePlaceholderVisibleOnBlur(this.getEditorFromReactRef());
    if (typeof this.props.onBlur === "function") {
      this.props.onBlur();
    }
  };

  //todo: consolidate the setState to one call as it renders everytime
  handleFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ isEditOn: true });
    this.handlePlaceholderVisibleOnFocus(this.getEditorFromReactRef());
    if (typeof this.props.onFocus === "function") {
      this.props.onFocus();
    }
  };

  handlePlaceholderVisibleOnFocus(editor) {
    if (editor.placeholder.isVisible() && this.props.autoSelectOnFocus) {
      editor.html.set(this.props.placeholderText);
      editor.commands.selectAll();
      this.setState({ isPlaceholderVisible: false });
    }
  }

  handlePlaceholderVisibleOnBlur(editor) {
    if (editor.placeholder.isVisible()) {
      this.setState({ isPlaceholderVisible: true });
    }
  }

  getEditorFromReactRef() {
    return this.editorRef.current.editor;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CustomStyle
        isPlaceholderVisible={this.state.isPlaceholderVisible}
        placeholderTextWidth={this.props.placeholderTextWidth}
        padding={this.props.padding} //this ensures that the text does not touch the border
        width={this.props.width}
        multiLine={this.props.multiLine}
        isEditOn={this.state.isEditOn}
      >
        <FroalaEditor
          ref={this.editorRef}
          model={this.props.text}
          onModelChange={this.props.handleTextChange}
          config={{
            enter: "", //this disables the auto adding of the <p> tag
            multiLine: this.props.multiLine,
            toolbarInline: true,
            initOnClick: true,
            toolbarButtons: [],
            placeholderText: this.props.placeholderText,
            events: {
              blur: this.handleBlur,
              keyup: this.handleKeyUp,
              click: this.handleFocus
            }
          }}
        />
      </CustomStyle>
    );
  }
}

CustomInlineFroalaEditor.defaultProps = {
  autoSelectOnFocus: true
};

export default CustomInlineFroalaEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Property `html` of `editor` can be undefined when option `initOnClick: true,` is used. Editor methods should be available but delayed initialization can result in other unexpected behaviour [later].

You can use events `initialized` or `initializationDelayed` for your customizations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using the initialized event. ```initialized: function() {console.log("initialized with", this.html)}```

still returns undefined

Comment: I would rather try `'initialized' : function(e, editor) {
      console.log('initialized', editor, editor.html);
    }` - `this` can be not what you want here

Comment: I tried the code block and the editor is still undefined I get  ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined```

Comment: Try to use something like https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg/blob/master/lib/FroalaEditor.jsx - it's already using ref fn, still valid method ... create [example] - it's hard to guess whats going on without that

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @xadm. Right now this has been de-prioritized will get back to it later.